# Less is adding unwanted code on url when compiled to css

Tags: css, visual-studio, compilation, less, web-essentials

So i have something like this:

```
@color1: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
@color2: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
#start-view .start1 {
    .imageGradientOverlay(@color1, @color2, "../images/start/start1.jpg");
}
```

variable for this is:

```
.imageGradientOverlay(@color1, @color2, @url-image) {
    background-image: 
        linear-gradient(@color1, @color2), 
        url(@url-image);

    background-image: 
        -webkit-linear-gradient(@color1, @color2), 
        url(@url-image);
}
```

and the compiled code looks like this:

```
#start-view .start1 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)), url("../../../images/start/start1.jpg");
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)), url("../../../images/start/start1.jpg");
}
```

The question is - Why is less when compiling adding two more `../../` ?

If i try to add this `/images/start/start1.jpg` the code is compiled fine but this is not what i need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [LESS options](http://lesscss.org/#client-side-usage-browser-options), I believe you have `rootpath` set to add that prefix. So reset the `rootpath` and it should be fine.

You can test it here - [LESS2CSS](http://less2css.org/), just add that option.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. I was using Visual Studio with Webessentials and the compilerconfig.json defaults file had "relativeUrls" set to true which caused this problem.